# Reveal/slide image using clipaths

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking to create an animation that slide an image but not using the traditional slide CSS animations, this not achieve the result I am looking for, so basically the animation contains 2 images, the two images are similar (contains the same content as the same sizes) but colors are inverted.

The code I implemented only slide the image to left or right, I'd like to do the same animations but keeping the image in the same place, like when it slides it reveals the background image content as it progress but colors inverted.

I was thinking to apply the animation to clipath crop rather than actual image, below is a working jsfiddle of the issue I am facing.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $(".reveal").toggleClass("show");
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center
}

.reveal {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.reveal:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/UBOmQ7T.jpg');
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.reveal.show:after {
  left: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reveal">
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/R6978y3.jpg' />
</div>
<br />
<button class="btn">Reveal!</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v7fte3m8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with multiple background. The trick is to make `background-clip` of one of them to be `content-box` then adjust the padding to create the reveal effect:

```css
.box { 
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
  background:
    url('https://i.imgur.com/UBOmQ7T.jpg'),
    url('https://i.imgur.com/R6978y3.jpg');
  background-clip:
    content-box,
    padding-box;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  
  transition:1s all;
  padding-left:0;
}

.box:hover {
  padding-left:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

In case you will always have image with inverted colors you can consider the original image and the `invert()` filter:

```css
.box { 
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
  background:
    url('https://i.imgur.com/R6978y3.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  background:inherit;
  background-clip:content-box;
  box-sizing:inherit;
  transition:1s all;
  padding-left:0;
  filter:invert(1);
}

.box:hover:before {
  padding-left:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```